# Triple bond inside escaped chemfig formula within chemformula's reaction

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, chemmacros, chemformula

I'm trying to include a molecular structure drawn with `chemfig` inside `chemformula`'s `reaction` environment by escaping it with `"…"`. It all worked fine until I stumbled upon a structure with a triple bond. According to `chemfig`'s manual, `~` is used exclusively for drawing a triple bond, however, when placed inside `reaction`, `~` character is ignored or incorrectly interpreted (single and double bonds are displayed fine):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules={all}}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    A + B + C + D -> "\chemfig{A-[::30]B=[::30]C~[:30]D}"
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `chemformula` v4.15g, `chemmacros` v5.8f and `chemfig` v1.41 from the fully up-to-date (as of 2019-10-08) TeX Live 2019.

Comment: From the `chemformula` manual (see section 8.1, page 21): "If you put something between `" "` or `' '` then the input will be treated as normal text, except that spaces are not allowed and have to be input with `~`." This might be the reason for the output you get.

Comment: This will work in version 4.15h (2019/10/13) of `chemformula` which I've just uploaded to CTAN

Comment: @clemens Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `chemformula` v4.15h (2019/10/13) the MWE works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}[2019/10/13] % v4.15h or newer
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions}}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  A + B + C + D -> "\chemfig{A-[::30]B=[::30]C~[:30]D}"
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules={all}}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\abcd}{\chemfig{A-[::30]B=[::30]C~[:30]D}}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    A + B + C + D -> "\abcd"
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```